# as3 LiveStream Camera and Microphone

Tags: actionscript-3, red5, http-live-streaming, netstream

These are my configurations code of live stream video/ audio in my swf file. We use red5 media server .

```
function configureMic()
                    {
                        mic.rate = 22;
                        mic.gain = 50;
                        mic.setLoopBack(true);
                        mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);

                    }

                function configureCam()
                {
                    camera.setLoopback(true);
                    camera.setMode(320,240,15);
                    camera.setKeyFrameInterval(30);
                    camera.setQuality(0,70);

                }
```

My question is what is the optimal configuration for best performance/quality ?

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is pretty broad; best quality and performance given what? A clients bandwidth and environment is not taken into account; it would vary from client to client anyway. Your code snippet looks just fine for testing out your app. The changes I would make would be the following:

- No loopback for the mic
- For an FPS of 15, your KeyFrameInterval should be 150
- For higher quality video images, set Quality to 90 as opposed to your 70